# How can I prove $ \ \bigcap_p \mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

### p-adic numbers

How can I  prove  $ \ \bigcap_p \mathbb{Z}_p=\mathbb{Z}, \ $ where $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is the ring of p-adic integer.

We have information from definition of projective or inverse limit that $\mathbb{Z}_p=\lim_{n} \mathbb{Z}/p^n$.

Also we know that each $\mathbb{Z}_p$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$ since it is a completion of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Also we  have the natural maps $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_p$ and $ p^n \mathbb{Z} \to p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$ which give rise to the natural map $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_p/p^n \mathbb{Z}_p$.

How does these informations helps us to prove the above result?

Comment: How do you define such an intersection? The sets $\Bbb Z_p$ are not in a common "environment set" containing all of them.

Comment: @Crostul, I am not defining it. it is infact a well known result and intersection taken over all primes $p$ producing the set $\mathbb{Z}$ but I don't have the proof. Also remember that each $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ and hence $\mathbb{Z}_p \supset \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: [Read the answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600202/intersection-of-p-adic-integers) to understand my comment. An intersection of arbitrary sets is not defined, if they are not subsets of a "big" set which contains all of them. In this sense, the intersection $\bigcap_p \Bbb Z_p$ is not defined. I would say that it's the empty set, since all the $\Bbb Z_p$ are formally disjoint.

Comment: @Crostul, But each $\mathbb{Z}_p$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$. Suppose the intersection is wrong, how can one still say the above result is true with suitable definition of $intersection$ ?

Comment: Each $\Bbb Z_p$ contains *a copy of* $\Bbb Z$. But copies of different $\Bbb Z_p$s are different. They are not the same set.

Comment: @Crostul, so i think the source file, from where I got the result, is wrong. What do you think ?

Comment: I think that you should share your source, hoping that we can find a definition of $\bigcap_p \Bbb Z_p$ there. This is the main purpose of my first comment: first you have to define what $\bigcap_p \Bbb Z_p$ is, then from the definition it will naturally arise that it is equal to $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I think a proper interpretation is that the cone of inclusions $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z_p$ is universal among such cones of ring-monomorphisms.

Comment: @Crostul, Can you show that copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ inside of different $\mathbb{Z}_p$s are different  ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though there is wide agreement about how $p$-adic integers *behave*, this agreement does not extend to how they are *represented* in set theory. There are several possible constructions which all produce isomorphic rings -- each author chooses one of them and then feels justified in calling the thing he has defined *the* $p$-adic integers. This usually doesn't produce a problem because the results are indeed isomorphic -- but it does matter for something like $\bigcap_p \mathbb Z_p$ which *doesn't* depend only on the internal structure of each $\mathbb Z_p$.

1. You could define $\mathbb Z_p$ as the $p$-adic [metric completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) of $\mathbb Z$. Then by definition every $\mathbb Z_p$ would contain $\mathbb Z$ as a subset -- but what *else* they have in common depends on exactly how you construct "the completion", which is often only *defined* up to isomorphism by a universal property.

   If you construct the completion by taking *equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences*, we run into a problem that becomes a common theme below -- namely that even though each ordinary integer has a sequence that *represents it* canonically in each of the $\mathbb Z_p$s, the *equivalence classes* that contain this canonical representative are not the same in different $\mathbb Z_p$s. The *actual* set-theoretic intersection becomes empty in that case.
2. Another common definition of a more algebraic slant is as an [inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit):

   > A $p$-adic integer is a function $f$ with domain $\mathbb N_+$ such that for each $n$ we have $f(n)\in \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z$, and additionally (... the $f(n)$s agree in some appropriate way ...)

   Unfortunately, this doesn't resolve our question, because it now depends on, for example, what the intersection of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/q\mathbb Z$ is. And there's a similar problem in defining the set-theoretic identity of those rings. Algebraists hugely prefer to let the elements of $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ be *equivalence classes*, and if we use *that* definition we get
   $ \bigcap_p Z_p = \varnothing $
   because there is no possible $f(1)$ that is at the same time an equivalence class modulo $p$ and an equivalence class modulo $q$ for $p\ne q$.
3. On the other hand, people who want a more elementary (programmer-like) understanding of things might want to define the integers modulo $p^n$ as the set $\{0,1,\ldots,p^n-1\}$ with particular addition and multiplication operations on it. In that case the sequences
   $$ (0,0,0,\ldots) \qquad\text{and}\qquad (1,1,1,\ldots) $$
   would be elements of every $\mathbb Z_p$, but nothing else would. So then we'd have $\bigcap_p\mathbb Z_p = \{0,1\}$.
4. We could also fuse the inverse limit construction with the construcion of modular arithmetic and define something like

   > A $p$-adic *pre-integer* is a function $f:\mathbb N_+ \to \mathbb Z$ such that $f(n)\equiv f(n+1) \pmod{p^n}$ for all $n$.
   >
   > A $p$-adic integer is an equivalence class of $p$-adic pre-integers under such-and-such equivalence relation.

   The goal of this might be to produce a clearer embedding of $\mathbb Z$ -- but it's actually not really an improvement for our purposes here. Even though we now seem to have $\mathbb Z$ embedded in $\bigcap_p\mathbb Z_p$ in the form of the constant sequences, that is only a *representatives*. The actual *equivalence* classes that encode the integers in each $\mathbb Z_p$ are still all different, so we still get $\bigcap_p\mathbb Z_p=\varnothing$.
5. Finally we could take a completely programmer-centric approach and define

   > A $p$-adic integer is any function $f:\mathbb N_+ \to \{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$.

   where the $f(n)$s are *single digits* and we then define addition and multiplication by the obvious generalization of the grade-school digit-by-digit operations for $\mathbb Z$ in base $p$.

   Now $\bigcap_p \mathbb Z_p$ consists of all infinite sequences of $\{0,1\}$ -- but in a way that is algebraically completely unsatisfying, because each such sequence *behaves* differently for different $p$s -- except for $(0,0,0,\ldots)$ and $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ which consistently represent $0$ and $1$.
6. I think there are also more esoteric constructions that would work, such as constructing $\mathbb Z_p$ as the quotient $\mathbb Z[[X]]/\langle X-p\rangle$ where $\mathbb Z[[X]]$ is the ring of formal power series with integer coefficients. Again this would lead to $\bigcap_p \mathbb Z_p$ being empty because none of the equivalence classes agree.

Now, for each of the above definitions we could "cheat" and explicitly *rename the elements* that correspond to ordinary integers, such that they are represented by the elements of our usual $\mathbb Z$. Then we indeed get $\bigcap_p \mathbb Z_p= \mathbb Z$, but *a priori* that is more a feature of the cheating we did to define $\mathbb Z_p$.

One might be able to find a precise sense in which $\mathbb Z$ is the *largest ring* that embeds in all the $\mathbb Z_p$ in a "sufficiently nice" way -- but that is something quite different from a set-theoretic *intersection*. (Though I suppose one could co-opt the $\bigcap$ symbol with a category-theoretic meaning that produces this outcome).

Comment: Several good points here. Just repeating my comment from [six years ago](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600202/11619). Each ring $\Bbb{Z}_p$ contains transcendental units, implying that we can embed $\Bbb{Z}[\pi]$ or $\Bbb{Z}[\pi,\pi^{-1}]$ into each and every one of them. There is obviously nothing canonical about those embeddings. Just bringing this up, because that *precise sense* is rather delicate. I, for one, would not want to attempt to give a precise meaning to the claim :-)

Comment: @Jyrki, good point. I've toned the last paragraph down a bit.

Comment: Perhaps we should just have closed this as a duplicate of that 2013 question. (I even noticed my previous answer earlier today because it got an upvote after Crostul's comment here linked to it, but managed to completely forget it by the time I came to _this_ question ... :-/ )

Comment: @HenningMakholm, your answer incite many important things

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to use any maps or heavy machinery, just work from the definitions:

Clearly $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \bigcap_{p}\mathbb{Z}_p$ because any integer is also a p-adic integer.

For $q = \frac{a}{b} \in \mathbb{Z}_p$, $gcd(b,p)=1$.

Therefore if $b$ is coprime to all primes $p$, indeed it is $1$. Therefore $q$ is an integer and you have the other inclusion.

Comment: What about those elements of $\Bbb{Z}_p$ that are not of the form $a/b$ with integers $a,b$. For example, both $\Bbb{Z}_5$ and $\Bbb{Z}_{13}$ contain two solutions of $x^2+1=0$. Are they in the intersection?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, but sir each $\mathbb{Z}_p$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$ being a completion

Comment: Correct, @M.A.SARKAR. But there are no solutions of $x^2+1=0$ in $\Bbb{Z}$. Are those solutions in the "intersection" $\Bbb{Z}_5\cap\Bbb{Z}_{13}$ or not?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, if both $\mathbb{Z}_5$ an $\mathbb{Z}_{13}$ contains the solutions of $x^2+1=0$, then obviously in the intersection

Comment: Why would that be the case, @M.A.SARKAR?  Both $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$ and $\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z}$ contain a solution of $2x=0$, but you would not place that solution in an intersection.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, oh sorry, I see it now. thanks

Comment: Could it be that this answer conflates the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb Z_p$ with the localisation of $\mathbb Z$ at the prime ideal $(p)$, usually denoted $\mathbb Z_{(p)}$? Because those all do lie in (or naturally identify with subsets of) a common "superset" (namely, $\mathbb Q$), and the argument in here would show their intersection is indeed $\bigcap \mathbb Z_{(p)} = \mathbb Z$. Whereas the argument here makes no sense for $p$-adic integers which are not $\in \mathbb Q$.